# Can I increase my hard disk space in virtual box which is running Windows 7 currently?

Tags: partitioning, virtualbox, hard-drive

I have my first attempt to install an OS using virtual box and for that I made a 25 gb partition to my hard disk and now I want to increase its size.  Is that valid, and if yes, how can i do it?

[image]

[image]

This is the current status of my virtual machine.  I have another question regarding 3d settings for Windows 7 which is installed in virtual box.
can virtual box support 3d games [image]

[image]
this is shown when i type the given commands in terminal

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For example in order to increase the virtual disk size to 60GB you need to run the following command:

```
VBoxManage modifyhd "/home/agha/VirtualBox VMs/agha rehan abbas/agha rehan abbas.vdi" -–resize 60000 (size is in MB)
```

Then you need to start you Windows machine and go to Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Computer Management -> Disk management right click the disk and select Extend volume to add the unallocated space to the current volume.

Comment: will this be completely safe

Comment: i mean is there any chance of losing memory and data of hard drive

Comment: normally no ... if by some means you lose power during the resize operation then yes :)

Comment: will you please check my edited question as i hav updated it because some error was displayed

Comment: sorry i have mistyped the resize parameter it --resize not -resize. It has double dashes

Comment: you mean before resize there should be two dashes

Comment: yes there are 2 dashes

Comment: again a new error is shown and my font size has been shrinked whike typing the command

Comment: the is a 's' at the end of the agha name. Please remove that s. Sorry once again for mistyping the path. it should be VBoxManage modifyhd "/home/agha/VirtualBox VMs/agha rehan abbas/agha rehan abbas.vdi" -–resize 60000

Comment: As said, it should be safe. But every time you play with disks and partitions, in whichever operating system, have a backup ready. Always.