# How to increase disk space given to Virtual Box VM through the GUI?

Tags: partitioning, virtualbox, virtualization, gui, disk-usage

My host is Ubuntu GNOME 15.10 with GNOME 3.18, and I am running Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 with GNOME 3.19 in a Virtual Box VM to which I gave 8 GB dynamically allocated disk space to start with. And I have run into a slight problem, I need to do an update in the guest, the update requires more disk space than is currently allocated to the VM. 
I have already looked at [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/466350/364819) but would like to know if there is a GUI way of doing it as I am having issues with VBoxManage. I would also like to know if once I have increased the disk space given to the guest if I need to do anything guest-side to mean that it gets the space and can use it?

Comment: I don't believe that there is a gui for this in Linux, I have been unable to find any info to the contrary.  After enlarging the size of the VM you will need to boot the VM with a Live image and use gparted or some similar program to enlarge the partition to use the entire disk just like a real HD

Comment: @TrailRider: Ok, could you please post that as an answer then. :)

Comment: ok as no one else has any more info I will.  I was hoping that someone had found out a way that I had missed but as it seems that is not the case I will post.

Comment: @TrailRider: By the way, I also figured out the command-line method and fixed my problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was also looking for this info a while ago, but after quite a bit of searching for an easy way to increase the size of a VirtualBox HD, I was unable to find any other way than the method you linked to.

I even searched Oracle’s  support website, which was where I found the `VBoxManage modify hd` method that you did, that was the only way mentioned for any host OS on Oracle's site, even Windows does not appear to have a GUI way of doing this.

---

As to the second part of your question I can at least answer that helpfully.

When enlarging the virtual HD it will only increase the size of the HD not the partitions on it.  You will have just blank, unformatted space at the end of the drive.

To use the rest of the HD you will need to boot into the VM using a Live image(i.e. an LiveCD or booting directly from the ISO, in my experience VirtualBox will not boot from a LiveUSB, but this may have changed with the most recent update).

After booting into the Live system and clicking "Try Ubuntu" you will need to use a partition editor like `gparted` to enlarge the existing partition to the size desired and then expand the file system to fill the space.

If you are just using the space for a new partition you *should* be able to just boot into the guest OS and format the new partition with a formatting program.  If you have a Windows guest I think that it still comes with some form of Drive Management program that can do this, but my latest experience with Window is Win 7 so I may be outdated.